# Smartgwt modal window. how to define a widget that caused it to redraw it?

Tags: java, event-handling, widget, smartgwt

That is what I'd like to ask - I've got this code:

```
winModal.addCloseClickHandler(new CloseClickHandler() {
        public void onCloseClick(CloseClickEvent event) {
               _addRedrawCodeHere_
               winModal.destroy();
        }
});
```

and I want to add here a functionality for redrawing a widget that caused this modal window.
Please help me guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try just calling the parent widget redraw?

```
class ILaunchedThatWinModal extends vLayout{

     //blablabla code here...

     public void launchWinModal(){
          final Window winModal = new Window();
          //configuring the winModal.
          winModal.addCloseClickHandler(new CloseClickHandler() {
                public void onCloseClick(CloseClickEvent event) {
                   ILaunchedThatWindModal.this.markForRedraw(); //<-Look here
                   winModal.destroy();
                }
           });
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But it would work if there is nothing more except parent widget. But if there is complex hierarchy of widgets it will cause to many redraws, but I want to redraw only one widget (the cause) instead of redrawing all page.

Comment: Well, then you need to keep a reference to the widget(the cause) and call markforRedraw in that one. That will not redraw the whole page.